# Error using "elasticbeanstalk:Describe" in IAM Policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-iam

I created this policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "elasticbeanstalk:UpdateApplicationVersion",
                "elasticbeanstalk:CreateApplicationVersion",
                "elasticbeanstalk:DeleteApplicationVersion"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "elasticbeanstalk:InApplication": [
                        "arn:aws:elasticbeanstalk:ap-south-1:123456789012:application/test"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "elasticbeanstalk:DescribeEvents",
                "elasticbeanstalk:DescribeApplications",
                "elasticbeanstalk:AddTags",
                "elasticbeanstalk:ListPlatformVersions"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:elasticbeanstalk:ap-south-1:123456789012:application/test"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "elasticbeanstalk:AddTags",
                "elasticbeanstalk:Describe*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:elasticbeanstalk:ap-south-1:123456789012:platform/*",
                "arn:aws:elasticbeanstalk:ap-south-1:123456789012:environment/*/*",
                "arn:aws:elasticbeanstalk:ap-south-1:123456789012:application/*",
                "arn:aws:elasticbeanstalk:ap-south-1:123456789012:solutionstack/*",
                "Condition": {
                    "StringEquals": {
                        "elasticbeanstalk:InApplication": [
                            "arn:aws:elasticbeanstalk:ap-south-1:123456789012:application/test"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
```

When I am review the policy I am getting:

> This policy defines some actions, resources, or conditions that do not provide permissions. To grant access, policies must have an action that has an applicable resource or condition.

When I remove `elasticbeanstalk:Describe*` from the policy it works, but I need to have it included.

Comment: You might try asking a specific question, and formatting your question wouldn't hurt.

Comment: hi all i need help to resolve this, when i remove "elasticbeanstalk:Describe*" from policy it has work but i need both,

Comment: It is not correctly closing the square bracket in the bottom `Resource` (before the `Condition`).

Comment: thanks john, but i dont know how to deploy code in stack overflow. i have full code but its shown error, and i have put close bracket also

Answer (score 1):

All of your resource elements are bad.  They can't be empty, at least make them wildcards (*).  Also "arn:aws:elasticbeanstalk:ap-south-1:123456789012:application/" is not correct, make sure to have a wildcard at the end there also
In your permissions you have "s3:".  You need a wildcard there also.
Also, if you are coding conditions resources can be of a wider scope.

I would suggest using the Visual Editor or spending more time learning IAM, you are missing the basics here.

Without more detail on the error your are seeing and telling us what you are actually trying to do can't help you much more.  Also, take it easy on the caps :)

Comment: while i am review the policy that time this summary has show (This policy defines some actions, resources, or conditions that do not provide permissions. To grant access, policies must have an action that has an applicable resource or condition. For details, choose Show remaining Learn more)

Comment: That would be s3: not being "s3:*".  I didn't look at your policy too deeply.  Please review it all.

Comment: "arn:aws:elasticbeanstalk:*:account_ID:application/*" is it right ?